# How to design a Context-Free Grammar and Pushdown Automaton for the following language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

How would you design a context-free grammar for the following language?
$$ 
L = \{a^{(n^3+1)}\mid n \geq 1\}
$$
And derive a Pushdown Automaton that accepts the same language.
Any help given would be greatly appreciated as I am completely lost and struggling to get the answer.

Comment: I would be slightly surprised if this language was context-free

Comment: Use the pumping lemma for context free languages to show that this language can not be context free. The issue here is that the cubes grow too fast to be controllable by a push down automaton. (It is even known that context-free languages with a one-letter alphabet have to be regular and thus non-linear exponents are not realizable.)

Answer (score 1):

Your language isn't context-free.

It is well-known that a unary language (a subset of $a^*$ for some letter $a$) is context-free iff it is regular iff the set $\{ n : a^n \in L \}$ is eventually periodic. You can check in any number of ways that $\{n^3+1 : n \geq 1\}$ isn't eventually periodic (for example, it has zero density yet isn't finite), and so the language is neither regular nor context-free.